# How to position graphics on top of page, and let the two-column text continue below it on the same page?

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

Since one month, I have started using LaTeX in Overleaf and I love it. Though there is still much to learn.

I am writing an ACM format paper and all my pages consist out of a two-column layout.

My question: How can I position a graphic on top of the page, and let the two-column text continue below it on the same page?

Currently what I get is the image does showcase on top of the page spanning over two columns. But the text of the second column runs through parts of the image that is spanning the second column.

- A couple of things:
- If I put '\onecolumn' before the '\begin{figure}' part, the spanning goes well, as it will span over a one-column \textwidth. But then the text must continue in \twocolumns after the image and this doesn't seem to work.
- If i don't add '\onecolumn', the image does span over two columns, but the text of the second column just overlays part of the graphs that is spanning the second column.

This is a sample of my setup:

```
\subsection{Front End}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{img/system.png}
\caption{System Design}%
\label{fig:System Design}%
\end{figure}

\subsection{Middleware layer}
\blindtext
```

If someone can review my actions, and please steer me into the right direction.

Comment: use `figure*` not `figure`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - It worked ! thanks so much.